# How to substract a column from cumulative sum in R

Tags: r

I have a DATAFRAME which looks like this. I want to substract the **cumulative sum** of **AMOUNT** WITH **TOTAL_AMOUNT** for each **ID** seperately. so the result must be grouped by ID

```
ID      AMOUNT     TOTAL_AMOUNT   
110      1250         4000           
110       250         4000           
110       350         4000          
111       985         3500           
111       440         3500          
111        50         3500           
112      1080         4000         
112       380         4000
```

After the calculation, my output should look something like this

```
 ID      AMOUNT     TOTAL_AMOUNT   CALCULATION(new column)**(TOTAL_AMOUNT-CUMSUM(AMOUNT)**
110      1250         4000           2750
110       250         4000           2500
110       350         4000           2150
111       985         3500           2515
111       440         3500           2075
111        50         3500           2025
112      1080         4000           2920
112       380         4000           2540
```

Comment: run `dput(yourdataframename)` in R then paste output here. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: In base R, you can do : `df$CALCULATION <- with(df, TOTAL_AMOUNT - ave(AMOUNT, ID, FUN = cumsum))`

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(cumsum = cumsum(AMOUNT),
         diff = TOTAL_AMOUNT-cumsum)
```